# HTTP request with fake identity or user agent

Tags: http, go

```
http.Get("http://Google.com")
```

I want to send a HTTP request with Go. Is there any way that I can manually modify my identity? I want to have fixed IP addresses and user agents when sending HTTP requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't "fake" your ip, you can use a proxy on another host.

However, you can fake the user agent:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://google.com", nil)
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.27 Safari/537.36`)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

If you do have a proxy you can create the client like this instead:

```
purl, err := url.Parse("http://444.555.666.777:8888")
client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(purl)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the user-agent, just do as OneOfOne said:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://google.com", nil)
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.27 Safari/537.36`)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

regarding to ip part, if you want to change the ip shown, you'll have to use a proxy.

You could do something called ip spoofing on the Go side but that would make the packages return to that address, which might not be yours.

Try to be more specific in respect to what you mean by "I want to have fixed IP addresses" and I'll change my answer to better answer that part.